# Suppress warning that comparison is always false due to constant being zero

Tags: c++, g++

I have found code of this form in a local project:

```
#include <iostream>

const unsigned LOWER_LIMIT = 0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        unsigned a = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (a < LOWER_LIMIT) {
        // if (a - LOWER_LIMIT > a) {
            std::cerr << "lower\n";
            a = LOWER_LIMIT;
        }
    }
}
```

The `atoi()` part is only for *runability* of the demo and is supplied from a different part of the software in the real case. Naturally this code produces a warning with a recent `g++ -Wall -Wextra`:

```
comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false
```

The maintainer does not want to change the comparison because the constant LOWER_LIMIT might be changed in the future and he wants it to still work without changes. Additionally he wants the type to be unsigned also. My first idea to suppress the warning is

```
if (a - LOWER_LIMIT > a) {
```

which uses an unsigned underflow. But this solution is somewhat hard to understand for some people. I found a different solution:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtype-limits"
if (a < LOWER_LIMIT) {
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This works, but I assume from the `GCC` part that this is not a portable solution.

Is there a portable, generic and easy to understand way to avoid this warning and still maintain the ability for some developer to simply change the constant without having to know about this part of the code base where the comparison is happening?

**EDIT:** I have a template solution for this, but it feels like overkill:

```
template<typename NumericTypeA, typename NumericTypeB>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_unsigned<NumericTypeA>::value &&
            std::is_unsigned<NumericTypeB>::value, bool >::type
is_smaller_than(NumericTypeA a, NumericTypeB b)
{
    return (a - b > a);
}

template<typename NumericTypeA, typename NumericTypeB>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<NumericTypeA>::value &&
            std::is_signed<NumericTypeB>::value, bool >::type
is_smaller_than(NumericTypeA a, NumericTypeB b)
{
    return (a < b);
}
```

**EDIT 2:** If the compiler detects that the comparison is always false, wouldn't it be necessary for it to check the following statement and detect that this is ok (also suggested in a response)?

```
if ((LOWER_LIMIT > 0) && (a < LOWER_LIMIT)) {
```

It kind of feels that the compiler should accept this without a warning, but unfortunately it does warn in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably ways to work around the check of compiler with extra layer:

```
if (std::less<>()(a, LOWER_LIMIT)) // extra function
```

Probably overkill with template:

```
template <std::size_t Limit>
struct DoesIfLess
{
    template <typename F>
    void operator ()(std::size_t a, F&&f) {
        if (a < Limit) {
            std::forward<F>(f)();
        }
    }
};

template <>
struct DoesIfLess<0>
{
    template <typename F>
    void operator ()(std::size_t, F&&) {}
};
```

And then

```
DoesIfLess<LOWER_LIMIT>(a, [&](){std::cerr << "lower\n"; a = LOWER_LIMIT; });
```

or with C++17

```
if constexpr (LOWER_LIMIT != 0) {
    if (a < LOWER_LIMIT) {
        std::cerr << "lower\n";
        a = LOWER_LIMIT;
    }
}
```

Comment: However, if I were a maintainer of the header, I would not let this piece of code in.

Comment: @user2079303 Why not?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux because it changes the conventional and readable `if (a < LOWER_LIMIT)` into a magical incantation `DoesIfLess<LOWER_LIMIT>(a, [&](){ ... });`. Just to suppress a warning.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: only the C++17 way is not hacky. Other are verbose and not really readable (and would probably require comment to say it is to avoid warning).

Comment: I have a similar template solution but it kind of seems overkill to me. I'll add it to my question.

Comment: @Jarod42 and the C++17 way doesn't work unfortunately: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1b6f75783f785df

Comment: I ended up using the `std::less<>()(a, LOWER_LIMIT)` solution, so i'm marking this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a portable #pragma?

No. `#pragma` is by definition implementation defined.

Warning options in particular vary wildly across compilers.

> The maintainer does not want ...

Since there is a maintainer involved, I presume that the code in question is in an included header provided by a third party.

You can configure your compiler to not report warnings from third party headers. In the case of GCC, you can use `-isystem` option in place of `-I`. This way *you* don't need to worry about *their* warnings.

If you want to support multiple platforms, you probably need to use a cross platform build system generator such as cmake. In cmake, you can designate system include dirs with the SYSTEM option - although not all systems necessarily support this concept.

Comment: it is like a third party vendor yes ... we are using CMake also, I will put that on my list of possible solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap your constant in a do nothing function that just returns the constant's value the warning should go away.

```
#include <iostream>

const unsigned LOWER_LIMIT = 0;

constexpr auto get_lower_limit() { return LOWER_LIMIT; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        unsigned a = atoi(argv[1]);

        if (a < get_lower_limit()) {
            std::cerr << "lower\n";
            a = LOWER_LIMIT;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this works -- but why? Shouldn't the compiler replace the whole thing with the constant and then shouldn't this generate the same warning? I might suggest making the whole constant into a function in this case.

Comment: It looks like gcc is looking for a very particular expression where a `const unsigned` *variable* compares less than zero. Removing `const` from `LOWER_LIMIT` also eliminates the warning, even if it's clear that it's value never changes (though I'm not recommending that solution).

Comment: @hochl I feel it's likely that if the warning accounted for inlining and other optimizations it would produce too many false positives. The warning may be intentionally limited in scope.

Comment: It still adds weight to the code, but I can't think of a cleaner way to avoid the warning. And it's properly portable.

Comment: turning `constexpr` into runtime value to avoid the warning :-/ Possibly in one strange line `if (a < [](){ return LOWER_LIMIT; }())`.